# ¿Por que es el error, en este fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Buenos días compañeros, estoy trabajando con fragmentos porque estoy implementando un TabHost, pero al parecer cabían muchas cosas al trabajar con los fragmentos, me surgió el error que aparece en la siguiente imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

implemente el fragmento de la siguiente forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

porque me marcaba error en la clase en donde llamo a este fragmento
de antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Descripción del error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Descripción 2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;


private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu_inicio, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.ContextMenuLogout:
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class);
            SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("DatosDelLogin", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.clear();
            editor.commit();

            startActivity(i);
            finish();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position){
            case 0:
                Concesionarios Tab1 = new Concesionarios();
                return Tab1;

            default:
                return null;
        }///poner los vinculos a las clases//------------------------------------
    }
```

Nuevo error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Error resuelto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que error muestra? coloca el puntero del mouse y te mostrará un texto. Lo que realizaste no tiene que con la solución del posible error. el métodod reload() se encuentra dentro de la clase Concesionarios ?

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, acabo de anexar una imagen con la descripción del error

Comment: Gracias por agregar el error, te indica que como estas usando "this", esta tomando el contexto de la clase Concesionario, en realidad debe ser el de la Activity, agregué respuesta. @AlexisCaballero

Comment: @AlexisCaballero que tal, podrias pasar tu codigo? o en que te basaste, necesito hacer algo como lo que tu, pero pues no se ve todo tu codigo xD.  Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La clase `Concesionarios` es un `Fragment` por lo tanto el contexto se obtiene mediante `getActivity()` que es la `Activity` que contiene el `Fragment`, de hecho es lo que indica el mensaje, el primer parametro debe ser la Activity, el segundo un ArrayList de objetos ItemEmpresas:

```
AdapterEmpresas(AppCompatActivity, ArrayList<ItemEmpresas>)
```

debes asegurar usar el contexto de la Activity:

```
//myAdapterEmp = new AdapterEmpresas(this, myItemEmp);
myAdapterEmp = new AdapterEmpresas(getActivity(), myItemEmp);
```

Comment: No funcionó, anexo una captura de pantalla de la descripción del error

Comment: Ah, ya veo es que estas abriendo el Fragmente desde un FragmentActivity no desde AppCompatActivity, asegura que la clase que abre el Fragment extienda en lugar de FragmentActivity  de AppCompatActivity. Imagino es MainActivity.

Comment: si, lo deje por defecto, entonces checaré eso y voy a ver que pasa muchas gracias

Comment: Ese es el problema, también puedes modificar el adapter para que en lugar de requerir AdapterEmpresas(AppCompatActivity, ArrayList<ItemEmpresas>) requiera un AdapterEmpresas(FragmentActivity, ArrayList<ItemEmpresas>)

Comment: al parecer si abre desde AppCompatActivity, anexo el código

Comment: Puse una captura con el fragmento de código que me solucionó el error pero al parecer surgió uno nuevo cuando se arregló el otro jaja

Comment: Ya veo! pero no abre directamente, abre por medio de un FragmentPagerAdapter no de la Activity! permiteme revisar que se podría hacer.

Comment: vale, muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Creo que ya resolvi el ultimo error, estaba regresando el rootView antes, por eso me marcaba el error, no se si este bien hacer eso pero se resolvió el error, ahora a probar, anexo imagen de como es que quedó

Comment: de hecho ese es otro error, recuerda que necesitas la vista raíz para obtener la referencia de los elementos dentro del layout.

Comment: Con respecto al otro error, debe funcionar si importas la clase Fragment de import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Comment: Ok entonces jajaja probaré las dos formas y de verdad muchas gracias por la ayuda :)

Comment: un placer, saludos! ᕦ /͠- ‿ ͝-\ ᕥ

Answer (score 0):

Hazlo de esta manera:

En tu clase Concesionarios:

```
public class Concesionarios extends fragment{
}
```

E importas en esa clase android.support.v4.app.Fragment

***Tienes que usar el mismo import fragment, en todas las clases que hereden de Fragment***

Para llamar al Fragment tienes que usar :

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Si tu clase importada fuese **android.app.Fragment**
No te haria falta el :

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
```

Podrías directamente con un

```
getActivity().getFragmentManager()
```

Espero que te sirva!

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, déjame ver si puedo resolver el error así

Comment: Es importante que todos los fragments que utilizas en tu Aplicación , tengan el mismo import; no es lo mismo ***(fragment.v4)*** que ***(fragment.v7)***

Comment: Se recomienda mas el v4 o el v7?

Comment: Uno tiene mas años que otro, es la única diferencia, pero los dos te sirven.

Comment: ok muchas gracias :)